# php searching a data base and displaying it

Tags: php, html, mysql

i have not done any php coding but i have done some html coding.
i am trying to make a page that searches a database for a tag and displays it in a table with the id and a link.

```
<?php
include('header.php'); 
include('mysql_connect.php');
if (@$_POST['search']) {
    if (@$_POST['tag']) {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `archives` WHERE `tag` =       '".$_POST['tag']."' ;");

        if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            echo("<table border=2><tr><td>id</td><td>link</td><td>tag</td></tr>");
            while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {
                echo("<tr>");
                foreach($line as $col_value = > $row_value) {
                    echo("<td>$row_value</td>");
                }
                echo("</tr>\n");
            }
            echo("</table>");
        }
    }
}
?>

<h2>title</h2>
<p>body text</p> 
</div>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input name="tag" type="text" />
    <input name="search" type="submit" value="search" />
</form>
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

I am having trouble displaying the data, it does return the id but that is all, and it does not even put the id into the table.

Comment: i have already checked php.net and many other stack over flow questions.

Comment: The MySQL extension is outdated! Please upgrade to PDO or MySQLi if you aren't using legacy code.

Comment: Also you need to look into prepared statements (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), inserting variables from a post like that makes it very easy for malicious users to do a sql injection attack.

Comment: you have to learn from zero...and step by step.. my friend! Buy a good book(s) and test over and over...and learn the right way.. is good to know about mysql_* function but learn from beginning PDO/MYSQLI! Good luck...

Comment: it is sort of working now, ti repeats the header over again for the amount of things in the data base with that tag. all i changed is the `pg_fetch_array()` to `mysql_fetch_array()`. i tried to change mysql_* to mysqli_*  but it did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing functions from different databases. `pg_fetch_array()` is for a PostgreSQL database while the rest is MySQL. The corresponding function would be `mysql_fetch_array()`.

Apart from that, you should not start new code with `mysql_*` functions as they are becoming deprecated. Use `mysqli_*` or PDO objects.

Comment: thank you for pointing out the `mysql_fetch_array()` problem. it did help once i changed it.